# can notepad (windows default editor) store font size?

Tags: text, fonts, font-size, notepad

I am eager to know that can i show font-size of any txt file 
in notepad in actually it was written ..?

actually i am eager to that **windows default editor** notepad can remember the file's font size
for example , i received a txt file from internet and i want to know in which font-size it was written?

Comment: @user1692407 He means that this is a site for programming questions, if you have questions regarding _using computers for other things than programming_, superuser.com is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, plain text files do not store any metadata, only the text itself.

Comment: exactly , is there any way to prove it?

Comment: i mean any documentation of notepad or on microsoft that says this ??

Comment: @user1692407 From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_(software)) `Notepad is a common text-only (plain text) editor. The resulting files—typically saved with the .txt extension—have no format tags or styles`.